# How many padlocks required to make the Eiffel tower fall over?

Tags: moment

Yes the title is an odd question, so I will provide a little background! Recently the sheer amount of padlocks on the Pont d'Art in Paris caused a part of its railing to fall off. Similar padlocks have been found on the Eiffel tower, so naturally the first question that came to my head was: "How many padlocks would have to be put on one side of the Eiffel tower before *it* falls over?"

**Assumptions**

1. The centre of mass of the Eiffel tower for the $x$ axis is directly through the middle of the tower
2. The $y$ position of the centre of mass doesn't really matter too much.
3. The tower will fall when it's centre of mass is just over the edge of the base
4. The tower doesn't bend, it just falls over
5. The number of padlocks $n$ is sufficiently large that the volume of padlocks will bulge over the edge of the base (therefore fulfilling assumption 3).
6. The padlocks and the tower are particles
7. The tower is not bolted to the ground, and is free to fall over

**Variables**

Half the width of base of tower $d \approx 50$m

Mass of tower $M \approx 1 \times 10^7$kg

Mass of padlock $m \approx 2.83 \times 10^{-2}$kg

Volume of padlock $V \approx 1.41 \times 10^{-5}$m$^3$

**Method**

The volume of the sphere of padlocks (of radius $x$) must be equal to the volume of $n$ padlocks:

$\frac{4\pi x^3}{3} = nV$

The centre of mass $x$ of the padlocks (as they form a clump) needs to be greater than $d$ hence:

$x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3nV}{4\pi}} \geq d$

and if we consider the centre of mass of the Eiffel tower to be at the origin, we can make the following equation:

$(M + mn)d = (nm)x \Rightarrow (M - nm)d = (nm)\sqrt[3]{\frac{3nV}{4\pi}}$

Solving the resulting quartic for $n$ (and subbing back into $x$) gives:

$n = 3.82 \times 10^{10}$ padlocks

$x = 50.5 \geq d \therefore$ condition 3 is fulfilled

Is this method providing anywhere near a reasonable estimation for the number of padlocks required to topple the Eiffel tower (given assumptions 1 & 4 at least), and how can it be improved?

(p.s. not sure on what the tags should be!)

Comment: Two problems I immediately see are: (a) the Tower is not square in shape and (b) the Tower is bolted to the ground.

Comment: @KyleKanos well, of course, the tower _is_ bolted to the ground so I should add that it isn't bolted as an assumption! And surely the Tower being a particle transcends the need to be more of a triangle?

Comment: @KyleKanos In any case, with the $x$ coordinate resting in the middle of the tower, surely it can be any symmetrical shape?

Comment: "The Tower isn't bolted to the ground" and "it will topple instead of bend" are assumptions so out of touch with reality that they would make any attempt at solving this question irrelevant.

Comment: You have arrived at a total padlock mass equal to 100 times the presumed mass of the Eiffel Tower. It seems a safe bet to assume that the tower would collapse way before that mass is achieved.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The problem is, only being an A level physics student, I am unable to deal with the calculations necessary to factor in both of those elements, that's the reason! But I do agree, the assumptions I have made make it very difficult to give an accurate answer.

Comment: I know this is hard, but it's not a question of whether answers will be accurate but whether they will be meaningful at all in any way. You would be better off estimating the tensile strength of the steel in use, and trying to account for the fact that the structure itself is very strong. Because of its shape it is *very* unlikely to topple before it collapses - that much should be intuitively evident.

Comment: This question should be migrated to  what-if.xkcd.com  :-)